# Cookiebot banner overlays footer section with imprint

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, cookiebot

i added the cookiebot plugin to my wordpress system and now i have the problem, that the imprint is not viewable when the banner is open.

I don't want the banner to come from the top.

I tried it with this:

```
.CybotCookiebotDialog {
margin-bottom: 368px;
}
```

But it's not showing up.

Thank you!

vera

Comment: The cookiebot div has no class. it has an ID called CybotCookiebotDialog.

Comment: oh thank you, but it`s still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

*You styled on a class it should be a div. You also styled on the wrong element it should be the footer. Your approach is not responsive cause the banner has different heights on different viewports. In answer 4 you'll find a solution*

---

Hey,

you've multiple problems.

### 1.

The Cookiebot div has an ID not a Class called `CybotCookiebotDialog`

so your code would be like this:

```
#CybotCookiebotDialog {
     margin-bottom: 368px;
}
```

---

### 2.

The cookiebot div is a `display: flex;` and the calculation of this is done without the padding, thats why you have no result there, if the is `position: sticky;` you would have 368px of nothing under the cookiebanner.

---

### 3.

What you want is to make the `footer` larger so the notice isn't over your imprint.
so you need to style this to your `footer` like

```
footer {
     margin-bottom: 368px;
}
```

But have in mind this isn't responsive and isn't looking to good on a mobile device etc. because the footer in this devices is often higher then it is on desktop.

---

### 4. *Answer*

So i created this code a good time ago cause i had the same problem.

First i created an element like this as last element before the `footer` ends

```
<div id="m-footer-spacer"></div>
```

have in mind that you can choose the `id` freely it's just the namespace i used.

then you add this js code it's partly in jquery but you can refactor it.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

if ($('#CybotCookiebotDialog:visible').length !== 0) {
    $("#m-footer-spacer").height($('#CybotCookiebotDialog').outerHeight());
}

});

function CookiebotCallback_OnDialogDisplay() {
    $("#m-footer-spacer").height($('#CybotCookiebotDialog').outerHeight());
}


function CookiebotCallback_OnLoad() {
    $("#m-footer-spacer").height(0);
}
```

`CybotCookiebotDialog:visible`: i check if the banner is open in the initial page view.

`CookiebotCallback_OnDialogDisplay` if the user is opening the banner again to change his consent etc. the `height` is added again.

`CookiebotCallback_OnLoad` this is triggered when the user clicks on ok no matter if he accepted or not. Its for setting the div back to 0px;

If you want to have a fallback you can add the styles in a `<noscript>` tag, have in mind that it's only in html5 valid to use the `<noscript>` tag in the `head`

*I intentionally did not use the `$('document').ready(function(){});` cause i had a bug with the cookiebot and this function. I don't know if it's fixed now.*

---

i hope it helps you. :)